# How to trace code coverage of scripts run in Python shell from an unit test?

Tags: python, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise to take code coverage of unit tests. The unit tests will open a Python shell and execute other Python scripts, for example, run execfile("other_script.py") in the Python shell.

However, VS is not aware of this external Python shell, and any functions called there, so it does not take any code coverage for functions or scripts run inside this external Python shell.

Is it possible to make Visual Studio also take coverage from the functions run in the external Python shell?

By Python shell, I mean the window that will open when you run the Python.exe on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run other scripts just do this:

```
import [script here]
```

You could also have different statements before that. Still I do not understand what you mean. Could you explain more?

Comment: Hi I add some more details in the original question, hope it makes it more clear